# how to assemble date and time from two different table columns

Tags: mysql, sql

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I have a requirement to return a result of a orders where the condition is that we have a `orderDate` which is Date field in a table and one `orderCloseTime` for the same order which is in different table having only time value.

I have to compare the `orderDate` with `now()` but the time should compare from `orderCLoseTime` column from another table.

i.e if the `orderCloseTime` is having data `2017-07-17 09:40:12` which is today but if it has passed the time `orderCloseTIme` then that data should not return in the query.

In Below query, if i have date as a future date then also it is not returning the data, it should only compare the today date with time.

EDIT:

```
select * 
from opsorder mbo 
where date(mbo.orderDate)>=date(now()) 
and storeId in
    (select storeid from store mbs 
        INNER JOIN  distributioncenter mbd on
        mbd.distributionCenterId = mbs.distributionCenterId 
        where mbd.orderCloseTime > curtime() 
        and date(mbo.orderDate)>=date(now())
    );
```

Comment: `SELECT orderDate + ' ' + cutOff`, Something like that

Comment: I have tried like this @Justcode but no help. Actually i want to compare orderDate with now() but the time in orderDate i want to assemble from a column from different table

Comment: @ADyson but the orderDate is also having the time entry

Comment: `SELECT DATE(orderDate) + ' ' + cutOff` @ADyson Aplologise for the plagurism

Comment: You'll have to clarify "i want to assemble" then. You want to add the times together? Or replace the time in orderDate with the time in cutOff?

Comment: @RiggsFolly correct, assuming the intent is to replace one time with the other. It's unclear IMO whether it's that, or the idea is to add the times together, or something else entirely.

Comment: @ADyson yes i want to replace the time in orderDate with the time cutoff

Comment: ok then well RiggsFolly's code should do that for you.

Comment: @ADyson Totally agree, was going to comment a very similiar request for clarity

Comment: @ADyson but the both column is in different tables.

Comment: so you'll have to include the other table in the query in whatever way is appropriate (join or subquery). If you show us the relationship between the tables then maybe someone can make an example. At the moment you haven't said which table cutOff is in or how it relates to mb_opsorder

Comment: @ADyson opsOrder is having one entry as store where store is having one dcid that dcId is having entry in distributionCenter table there for each dcid i have one cutOff time. 
I am trying like this: 
`select * from mb_opsorder where date(orderDate)+' '+ (select orderCloseTime from mb_distributionCenter where distributionCenterId = 
(select distributionCenterId from mb_store where storeId=1709))>=date(now()) and storeId =1709 ;`

Comment: in your original query why aren't you inner joining from mbo_opsorder to mb_store, instead of using a subquery? On the face of it there seems no reason to use a subquery. If you used a join you could then select cutOff directly from the query as that column would be available in the normal way. I've posted a suggest answer below. P.S. If your column names are actually orderDate and orderCloseTime why did you call them ordDate and cutOff in the question? That's just confusing.

Answer (score 0):

From your description of the data structure it seems that this should work. I couldn't see a reason for the use of a subquery instead of a join.

```
select 
 mbo.*,
 DATE(mbo.orderDate) + ' ' + mbd.orderCloseTime AS OrderCutOffTime
from mb_opsorder mbo 
  inner join mb_store mbs
    on mbo.storeId = mbs.storeid
  inner join  mb_distributioncenter mbd 
    on mbd.distributionCenterId = mbs.distributionCenterId 
where 
  addtime(date(mbo.orderDate), mbd.orderCloseTime) >= now()
```

Comment: In the end where you are comparing the date and time, if we keep the date as tomorrow date in `orderDate` and if the `orderCutOffTime` is over then also the query is not returning the list. My Requirement was like if the `orderDate` is equal to today's Date and the `orderCutOffTime` has crossed then it should not return the result but in above code if the `orderCutOffTIme` is crossed but the date is tomorrow then also its not returning the result. Same like the code which i have posted in the main thread.

Comment: "my requirement was". Well if that was your requirement you never stated it. You just asked how to output them together in the select (or at least, that's what we took to mean by the vague "assemble" wording, and you didn't contradict that). In that respect the query answers the question precisely. However, I'll update the answer with something that should work.

Comment: Apologies! i couldn't explained it well. I have edited that

Comment: No problem. Does my change to the query in the answer help you meet the requirement?

Comment: Its returning 0 result.

Comment: well without seeing a sample of your actual data I can't tell you if that's the right outcome or not.

Comment: I have uploaded the snap of my db

Comment: do you store timezone for the order as well? Not much point storing it for one but not the other, as you can't match them up / adjust for them? Or do you convert everything to the same timezone when you store it the DB?